# SSH port forwarding for VNC on remote server with agent forwarding

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel, vncserver

Trying to connect to a remote VNC server, such as one would with an SSH tunnel:

```
ssh -L 5901:127.0.0.1:5901 -N -f -l username server_ip_address
```

However, the VNC server can only accept connections from a jump server. Both the jump and remote server authorize connections from `key_rsa`.

I tried this but authentication fails:

```
ssh jump_server 'ssh -v -L 1111:127.0.0.1:1111 -N -f -l <user> <remote_server> -p <port>'
```

Ideally, I'd like to setup a host in the config file which launches the tunnel on the jump server.

[image]